# Is there a way to make a custom hook modify a global state on any call?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-custom-hooks, global-state

This is my custom hook:

```
function useFetch({url = '', method = 'get', body}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (async () => {
        const data = await fetch[method](url, body);
        setData(data);
      })();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("An error ocurred")
    }
  }, [url, method, body]);
  return [(!data && <LoadingIcon />, data, setData];
}
```

I want to execute setUserFeedbackMsg("An error ocurred"), which is part of a context component, every time an error ocurrs on any instantiation of the hook. Of course I could do it manually on every component that uses the hook, but I'm wondering if there's a way to condense it all in one place. Thank you!

Comment: A lot of people integrate context components into (you guessed it) [custom hooks](https://dev.to/alexandprivate/use-react-context-as-a-custom-hook-4ioc) that they can compose into other hooks such as your useFetch. Does that help answer your question? In other words, the answer to "but I'm wondering if there's a way to condense it all in one place" is to use a hook!

Comment: I don't know if I'm understading you comment, but my problem is that I want the custom hook to use a setter from a context it doesn't have access to, and it's only a simple call to a single setState()

Comment: I'll try to elaborate in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose your context (global state) into a hook that components and other hooks can access.

```js
// obviously, this has been simplified to help with the concept

// fake fetch
function fakeFetchThatErrs() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject("error msg from our api!"), 1500);
  });
}


// a custom hook to wrap our state 
function useUserFeedback() {
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState('');
  

  return {
    message,
    setMessage
  };
}

// our context
const UserFeedbackContext = React.createContext();

// a custom hook to access our context
function useUserFeedbackContext() {
  return React.useContext(UserFeedbackContext);
}

// the context provider component
function UserFeedbackProvider({ children }) {
  const feedback = useUserFeedback();
  return (<UserFeedbackContext.Provider value={feedback}>{children}
  </UserFeedbackContext.Provider>);
}

// your useFetch hook (without the loading component)
function useFetch() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  // here we use our custom hook to "hook" into the context so we can use the setter!
  const { setMessage } = useUserFeedbackContext();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // changing this because (a) StackOverflow snippets don't support JSX along with async/await and (b) no need to really fetch here, we'll fake it
     fakeFetchThatErrs().then((data) => {
       // write to our data
       setData(data);
     }).catch((err) => {
       console.log("Error:", err)
       // uh oh, error! write to our context 
       setMessage(err);
     });
    
  }, [setMessage]);
  return [data, setData];
}

// our demo app component
function App() {
  const [data] = useFetch();
  // consume our context!
  const { message } = useUserFeedbackContext();
  
  return data ? <div>Success: {data}</div> : message ? <div>Something went wrong: {message}</div> : <div>Fetching...</div>;
   
}

// don't forget to use our provider!
ReactDOM.render(<UserFeedbackProvider><App /></UserFeedbackProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here's what's happening here in a nutshell:

1. We have a state object that we can access via a hook, `useUserFeedback`.
2. We create a Context around this state object and wrap that in its own hook, `useUserFeedbackContext`. This way, we can easily access the state getter and setter in components and, importantly, other hooks!
3. Thus, we can use the `useUserFeedbackContext` hook in our `useFetch` hook to set the message state to an error assuming there is one.
4. A common question around this (apologies if you already know this) - *why can't we just use the `useUserFeedback` hook in `useFetch`?* The answer is an important concept in React - hooks share *behavior*, while Contexts share *state*. If we simply tried to use the `useUserFeedback` hook, each time we called `useFetch` would result in a new `''` `message` state object. Using Context, we share one `useUserFeedback` instantiation across the board.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought a function needed to be a children to use the context ^^". In my approach, I just added to the useFetch hook const {showFeedbackMsgModal} = useContext(userFeedbackContext);
One little detail is that the try catch  needs to be inside the iife in my example :)